# How to use airflow to SSH into a server, activate a conda env and then run a python_callable def that imports from the ssh session

Tags: python, ssh, airflow, conda

I'm a newbie to airflow.

I'm working with Ubuntu 22.04 server and I need to run a proprietary python lib (import arcpy) that only lives on a windows server 2019. I've made a conda env on the win system and i can ssh into, activate, and run a local(win) python file. I would like to use the python_callable method for parsing out the tasks vs. running an entire py script. Is there a way to do this?

```
def myDef(**context):
    xcom_stdout = context["task_instance"].xcom_pull(task_ids="ssh_conn_task")
    import needed_propority_package
    needed_propority_package.dosomething

    t1 = SSHOperator(

        ssh_conn_id = 'ssh_conn_task',
        command =r"conda activate path/to/conda/env && python",
        task_id='test_ssh_operator1',
        do_xcom_push=True,
        cmd_timeout=600,

    )

    t2 = ShortCircuitOperator(
        task_id='shortcircuitop',
        python_callable=myDef,
        provide_context=True,
        
    )
```